# Christmas Eve problem:dynamic-programming

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

On Christmas Eve, Allie decides to go to each of the houses in her area and ask for donations so as to collect X units of money.

At each house, she asks for the remaining amount of money she requires. Each house gives less than the minimum amount given by the previous houses except the first house which give a random amount between 0 and X.

There is a total of Y houses in her area She only visits the houses until she gets a total of x units of money. In how many ways she collect exactly x units of money from Y houses?

Input Specification

input1: X total amount of money she requires.

input2: Y total houses in her area

Example1:

input1:5

input2:5

output:3

Explanation:
3 Possible ways, 5 from first house or 4 from first house and 1 from second house or 3 from first house and 2 from second house.

.......................

I can't able to build the logic to write code. If you know the solution please help! I am trying this from last 2 days.

Comment: In Example1 that you described, did you mean that input2 is 2, not 5? I don't understand why only two houses participate in the solution you describe for that example.

Answer (score 1):

Call `W(X,Y,C)` the number of ways to collect amount `X` from a number `Y` of houses, knowing that each house will give at most `C`.

(Your problem states that originally, `C=X`; so the solution you will look for is `W(X,Y,X)`.)

Now imagine you are given `X`, `Y` and `C`. Consider the amount `A` given by the first house. `A` can be any number in the range `[0,C]`. For every choice of `A`, the number of ways to complete the sum with the remaining houses is `W(X-A, Y-1, min(A-1, X-A))` because: the remaining amount to collect after the first house has given `A` is `X-A`; the remaining number of houses is `Y-1`; the other houses will give less than `A` (so at most `A-1`), and at most `X-A` since this is the remaining amount to collect.

This gives you a recurrence relation: `W(X,Y,C) = sum for A in [0..C] of: W(X-A, Y-1, min(A-1, X-A))`.

You can also figure out the base cases: `W(0,Y,C) = 1` because there is only one way to give 0. `W(X,0,C) = 0` if `X` is nonzero, because if there are no houses left, then the money cannot be collected. `W(X, 1, C) = 1` if `C >= X` because there is only one way for one house alone to give all the money. `W(X, 1, C) = 0` if C < X because there is no way for one house to give X if that house is allowed to give at most C < X.

You can use the recurrence relation and the base cases to fill an array in a classical dynamic programming way. Then the answer you are looking for will be in cell `W(X,Y,X)`.

There might be a smarter way with a two-dimensional array depending only on (X,Y) instead of (X,Y,C), but the constraint "Each house gives less than the minimum amount given by the previous houses" makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this question from a java test I gave long ago. It is easy if you understand the nature of this dynamic programming problem and its recursive nature.

```
public class Example2 {

    // this will be the solution
    static int solutionCount = 0;



    public static void canCollect(int remainingAmount, int remainingHouses, int previousAmount) {

        if (remainingHouses == 0)
            return;

        if (remainingAmount < 0)
            return;

        if (remainingAmount == 0) {
            solutionCount++;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < previousAmount; i++) {
            //deduct amount collected from this house-visit (i), deduct 1 from remaining houses, and set previousAmount to what you are collecting here
            canCollect(remainingAmount - i, remainingHouses - 1, i);
        }

    }
    
    
    // This is your solution function, although you'll need to change it enough to satisfy test-cases.
    public static int solutionFunction(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            canCollect(x - i, y-1, i);
        }
        return solutionCount;
    }

    
    //main is just to execute it here. Omit it in your submission
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(solutionFunction(5,5)); //3
    }

}
```